# listing files in UNIX owned by a particular user

Tags: linux, unix

How do I list the files owned by a particular user in UNIX ?.

If I use **ls - l** command in a **shared directory** ,it lists all the files with the details .This shared directory contains many files created by many users in a group and I am in a situation where I want to see the files created only by a particular user. Is there any listing command to give **username** as the input. 
Refer below example,

**command : ls - l**

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 user_1     main 4.0K    Feb 12 16:43 proj_1
drwxrws---   6 user_2     main  20M    Feb 18 11:07 proj_2
drwxr-xr-x   3 user_1     main 1.3M    Feb 18 00:18 proj_3
drwxrwsr-x   2 user_2     main  8.0K   Dec 27 01:23 proj_4
drwxrwsr-x   2 user_3     main  8.1K   Dec 27 01:23 proj_5
```

I am looking for a command to display only the files created by the **user_2** with my expected output as below ,

```
   drwxrws---   6 user_2     main  20M    Feb 18 11:07 proj_2
   drwxrwsr-x   2 user_2     main  8.0K   Dec 27 01:23 proj_4
```

Kindly let me know if there is a way .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to use awk togheter with ls -l

```
ls -l | awk '$3=="user_2" { print $0 }'
```

this will print all lines where third field (user) matches "user_2"

Comment: Thanks . Now I have another requirement where I want to list all the **.txt** files in the current directory(I have more other file types) , I tried using **ls| awk '$0=="*.txt" {print $0 }'** . Please let me know if I can use **awk** for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

You simply can use the `find`command like this:

> find . -maxdepth 1 -user some_user -exec ls -lsad {} \;

Why the options are used:

- `maxdepth` we only want to see current directory level
- `user` we only want to see files owned by given user
- `exec` lets do something with the found file

What we want do with the file:

`ls -lsad` gives you the long list of current file, if it is a directory, don't go into it.

Comment: Thank you. Its helpful , however is it possible to display every detail of a file (permission,size ,date .etc) like in the format of my example ?

Comment: @SreejinTJ: Have you tried it out? It is exactly printing what you have given in the example!

Comment: Yes. I have tried **find -maxdepth 3 -user user_2** , it displays the outputs **proj_2  and proj_4** as expected but similar to the output format of **ls**  command . Just wondering if I can see the output in the display format as of **ls-l** command

Comment: @SreejinTJ: You can have it every format you like. Simple add the command you want to use to display your files with after the exec clause.

Comment: Got it by using -exec .Thank you